# How to cache requirements for a Django project on Travis-CI?

Tags: python, django, travis-ci, requirements.txt

As Travis-CI is evolving and extending its feature set it naturally becomes nicer and nicer to use. I recently [read this article](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/speeding-up-the-build/) about "Speeding up the build". A build for the Django project I am working on takes ~25-30 minutes. Almost half of this time is spent on creating the virtualenv, i.e. installing the project's requirements. The other half of the time is used for the actual test run.

There are efforts on cutting down runtime for tests. Yet, I was wondering whether a bigger speed-up was *up-for-grabs* by caching or bundling the project's requirements. As for Plone there seem to be [some options](http://datakurre.pandala.org/2012/09/speed-up-your-plone-add-on-tests-on.html) as it uses buildout. I was also looking at [WAD](https://github.com/Fingertips/WAD). Of course, when caching the requirements they will need to get invalidated upon a requirements update.

Has anyone made any Travis build speed improvements for a (Django) project by cutting down setup time?

Answer (score 19):

**Update** This is now a first class feature of Travis: http://blog.travis-ci.com/2013-12-05-speed-up-your-builds-cache-your-dependencies/

I've just been playing around with this, and it looks like you can cache the virtualenv site-packages like this (update the path to your python version):

```
cache:
  directories:
    - /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

There's a little issue that it doesn't cache the `bin` or the `src` directories. I tried caching the whole virtualenv directory, but I get strange errors for dependencies installed via git into the `src` directory.

You are still left with the problem of invalidating old requirements. if you remove something from the requirements, it will persist in the virtualenv so you either have to explicitly remove it with pip (`pip remove foo`) or wait until Travis create an API to invalidate the cache...

The other option is to use the `--download-cache` option for pip, then add that directory to the cache:

```
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.pip-cache/

install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt --download-cache $HOME/.pip-cache
```

This will make the downloads faster, but it will still have to compile and install all of the requirements!

Comment: It's officially a feature now including an invalidation API http://about.travis-ci.org/blog/2013-12-05-speed-up-your-builds-cache-your-dependencies/ Yet, they don't get specific for pip caching.

Comment: thank you! pip install with --download-cache works great for me; build time went from 15m to 3m :)

Comment: You could also append "PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE=$HOME/.pip-cache" to your "env" lines in .travis.yml (instead of --download-cache on the pip command line) and this will be inherited by any tox-run pip commands as well.

Comment: Instructions on caching pip dependencies can be found here: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#pip-cache

Comment: Note this info is out of date now, Using it throws: `DEPRECATION: --download-cache has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Pip now automatically uses and configures its cache.`

Answer (score 10):

This has gotten even easier over the years. The latest way is:

```
cache: pip
```

That's it.

Comment: the other answers are good if your language is different than the cache, for example using a ruby image but running python script (while getting python using addons>apt>packages)

Answer (score 6):

With pip 7:

```
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.pip-cache/

install:
  - pip install --upgrade pip
  - pip install -r requirements.txt --cache-dir $HOME/.pip-cache
```